# RouteProvider Not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

i m trying to use routeProvider in angular but it doesn't working 
my html

```
 <html>
<head>      
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Myapp">
     <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

here is app.js

```
var app = angular.module('Myapp',[]);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",
        {
        templateUrl:'data.html',
        controller: 'myctrl'
        }
    )
});
app.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.model= {
        msg:"Route Worked"
    }
});
```

my template

```
<h1>{{model.msg}}</h1>
```

Comment: Do you getting any error in console ? Its seems you did not added `ngRoute` as  dependency in your `app` module.

Comment: yes   .Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=Myapp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A135)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4120s @ angular.js:323g @ angular.js:4081ab @ angular.js:4007d @ angular.js:1445tc @ angular.js:1466Jd @ angular.js:1360(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26176a @ angular.js:2744c @ angular.js:3014

Comment: You have to install `ngRoute` and load `ngRoute` in your app module as dependency.

Comment: i think this is due to deprecation...

Comment: how ..please can you provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html** include `<script>` for ngRoute.

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="Myapp">
         <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('Myapp',["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",
        {
            templateUrl:'data.html',
            controller: 'myctrl'
        }
    )
});

app.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.model= {
        msg:"Route Worked"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `angular-route` first and include in your project. Then load module in your application like this

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

Further [Documention](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) for detail.

Comment: yes i tried..but its not working...is there any problem with my code.i m getting this error in console                                                                                                         angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=Myapp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4120s @ angular.js:323g @ angular.js:4081ab